# how to get the file path for the ipython notebook in use? (the equivalent to __file__)

Tags: python, jupyter

I want to change dir to the parent dir of my jupyter notebook.

I can not take the notebook path using `os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))` as `__file__` is not defined.

How can I get the dir of the ipynb file I am using in order to os.chdir() to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10123

The reason is because you're always running in the kernel, and in theory multiple notebooks could connect to that kernel.

However - by default if you're starting a notebook, the current working directory is set to the path of the notebook.  So the closest, is to call `os.getcwd()`

I just created the most boring [published notebook example to demonstrate this](https://www.saturncloud.io/published/hugo/path_example), you can see that, [this notebook reflects it's path](https://www.saturncloud.io/published/hugo/path_example/path_example/path1.ipynb), and [this one that's in a subdirectory also reflects the proper path](https://www.saturncloud.io/published/hugo/path_example/path_example/subdir/path2.ipynb)

Comment: If you're going to include sources that you have written, you need to make it clear that you are the author. See [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way/94027#94027). Specifically: *"you identify the author (yourself, ...)"*

Comment: Thanks!  I'm a bit new obviously