# path problem : NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

```
import os.path as osp
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch_geometric.datasets import MNISTSuperpixels
import torch_geometric.transforms as T
from torch_geometric.data import DataLoader
from torch_geometric.utils import normalized_cut
from torch_geometric.nn import (NNConv, graclus, max_pool, max_pool_x, global_mean_pool)

path = osp.join(osp.dirname(osp.realpath(__file__)), '..', 'data', 'MNIST')

transform = T.Cartesian(cat=False)
train_dataset = MNISTSuperpixels(path, True, transform=transform)
test_dataset = MNISTSuperpixels(path, False, transform=transform)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)
d = train_dataset
```

I'm trying to use MNISTSuperpixels data for graph convolution, but I have some troubles using the example code.
Most of scripts were using
`path = osp.join(osp.dirname(osp.realpath(__file__)), '..', 'data', 'MNIST')`
However, they gave me an error
`NameError: name '__file__' is not defined` and I don't understand what `osp.realpath(__file__)` really means.

I'm using Jupyter notebook on Ubuntu, and my working directory is

```
print(os.getcwd())
/home/hkimlx/GDL/pytorch_geometric/examples
```

which is the same directory where the sample code `mnist_nn_conv.py` is located.

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56665042/8805293)

Answer (score 13):

In notebook, you need to use double quoted "__file__" as in `osp.realpath("__file__")` instead of `osp.realpath(__file__)`

Sourced from: [https://queirozf.com/entries/python-working-with-paths-the-filesystem#-nameerror-name-'**file**'-is-not-defined](https://queirozf.com/entries/python-working-with-paths-the-filesystem#-nameerror-name-%27__file__%27-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

> `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file. The `__file__` attribute may be missing
> for certain types of modules, such as C modules that are statically
> linked into the interpreter; for extension modules loaded dynamically
> from a shared library, it is the pathname of the shared library file.

According the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52119628/6653105) you can't get the path of a notebook pragrammatically. Use os.getcwd() as a workaround.

Comment: What does 'loaded from a file' mean? Based on your saying, I cannot solve this error while using jupyter notebook? but I have the same error when I use command prompt.

Comment: `__file__` is optional. Seems Jupiter doesn't set the var in a notebook.