# How do I resolve this pathlib _file_ name error in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter, nameerror, pathlib

```
---> 84     filepath = Path(__file__)  # this not part of course, got tip from friend
     85     data = {
     86         "W": Path(f"{filepath.parent}/washington.csv"),
     87         "C": Path(f"{filepath.parent}/chicago.csv"),
     88         "N": Path(f"{filepath.parent}/new_york_city.csv"),
     89     }
     91     df = pd.read_csv(data[city].as_posix())

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

I get this name error in Jupyter but it works fine in VSCode and PyCharm. The files are in the same directory as the script file.
How do I resolve it?

Googled pathlib error in Jupyter and come across a stack about that there is another way than pathlib. eg os.path. Anyone knows how to use this to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question from user "peng" in this stack:

[path problem : NameError: name '__file__' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583062/path-problem-nameerror-name-file-is-not-defined)

adding quotes " around _file solved the error

(__ file__) --> ("__ file__")